# Forbid object changes outside of a transaction

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

we recently stumbled over a behaviour of NHibernate that gave us a real headache ;).

Lets look at the following example:

```
declare x
open transaction
  create and persist object x
commit transaction

change object x

open other transaction
  do nothing
close transaction
```

It hit us as a surprise, that the changes made to 'x' outside of the second transaction where commited to the database (although this behaviour makes also sense to me, after i thought about it). In our architecture this is somewhat of a problem, hence we were used to a different behaviour in the world we came from ;).

Now the questions:

1. Is it possible to forbid object changes outside of a transaction with NHibernate (e.g. throw an exception)?
2. Is it possible to only commit the changes, that were actually made inside of the current transaction?
3. Is there some completly different thing, that we could do to enforce that changes to persistent Objects are made only in a particular scope (using-directive, class, namespace, etc)?

Thanks for your thougths, BaSche

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would answer your questions no, no and no. Of course anything is possible, for example you could do something ugly with INotifyPropertyChanged and throw an exception if there's no transaction. But NHibernate is not designed to work as you desire.

NHibernate is designed to allow your objects to be ignorant of the persistence layer and it mostly succeeds in these (with some notable exceptions like requiring virtual for lazy loading). An NHibernate transaction applies to sync'ing object state with the database, not with changes to the objects themselves. Also, you would have to be able to rollback changes to an object if the transaction is aborted and that's challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Object x wasn't change outside of a transaction, because when you open session you create transaction not explicit. When you called transaction.Commit() or when you closed session it was done session.Flush(), and all your changes were saved.

Comment: Thats exactly what happens. My question is, can i change this behaviour? Our architecture defines exactly one tier that is responsible for transactions. This is done via interceptors that open/commit/rollback transactions before respectivly after the call of an annotated method (or class). Now we want to enforce, that changes on persisted objects have to be made inside of a transaction. This way we can enforce that all changes on our business model are made transactional, safe and "clean" in one place.

Comment: You cannot do that. You shouldn't use implicit transaction: http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions.
But if you want that entity doesn't change you can use session.Evict(), and it'll be detach from session, and any changes won't be save.

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for sharing the link. Anyway, we don't use implicit transactions, we explicitly anotate some ServiceInterfaces as being transactional (as described above).